# modeling feature set with text documents

Tags: machine-learning

Example:

I have m sets of ~1000 text documents, ~10 are predictive of a binary result,  roughly 990 aren't.

I want to train a classifier to take a set of documents and predict the binary result.

Assume for discussion that the documents each map the text to 100 features.

How is this modeled in terms of training examples and features? Do I merge all the text together and map it to a fixed set of features? Do I have 100 features per document * ~1000 documents (100,000 features) and one training example per set of documents? Do I classify each document separately and analyze the resulting set of confidences as they relate to the final binary prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would want to approach it as a two stage problem.

Stage 1: predict the relevancy of a document from the set of 1000. For best combination with stage 2, use something probabilistic (logistic regression is a good start).

Stage 2: Define features on the output of stage 1 to determine the answer to the ultimate question. These could be things like the counts of words for the n most relevant docs from stage 1, the probability of the most probable document, the 99th percentile of those probabilities, variances in probabilities, etc. Whatever you think will get you the correct answer (experiment!)

The reason for this is as follows: concatenating documents together will drown you in irrelevant information. You'll spend ages trying to figure out which words/features allow actual separation between the classes.

On the other hand, if you concatenate feature vectors together, you'll run into an exchangeability problem. By that I mean, word 1 in document 1 will be in position 1, word 1 in document 2 will be in position 1001, in document 3 it will be in position 2001, etc. and there will be no way to know that the features are all related. Furthermore, an alternate presentation of the order of the documents would lead to the positions in the feature vector changing its order, and your learning algorithm won't be smart to this. Equally valid presentations of the document orders will lead to completely different results in an entirely non-deterministic and unsatisfying way (unless you spend a long time designing a custom classifier that's not afficted with this problem, which might ultimately be necessary but it's not the thing I'd start with).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and I've been thinking about how to achieve stage 1, I think that's where my real problem lies, I'll open up another more specific question about achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to handle text documents is with a [bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). The class proportions are irrelevant. Each word gets mapped to a unique index. Make the value at that index equal to the number of times that token occurs (there are smarter things to do). The number of features/dimension is then the number of unique tokens/words in your corpus.  There are manny issues with this, and some of them are [discussed here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-term-vocabulary-and-postings-lists-1.html). But it works well enough for many things.

Comment: So you suggest combining all text documents into one master right. Will the fact that 99% of the documents text be irrelevant be an issue in this case?

Comment: That is not at all what I said. Please read about what I posted.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow then, if I have 1000 documents, and the set of documents in their entirety is what predicts a single binary result; and I have m sets of documents; then the bag-of-words model seems to suggest that I combine all 1000 documents in each such set into a bag-of-words (aka "into one master" in my words). If you're not suggesting that I merge the 1000 documents into a common "bag of words" I'm not following your train of thought yet. From the way I read the bag-of-words approach I get the sense that the 99% of irrelevant documents/words are going to drown out those relevant.